# Will .NET Framework supports Azure Data Lake Gen 2?

Tags: azure-data-lake-gen2

We have the Web Job implemented with .NET Framework which are pointing to Azure Data Lake Gen 1.

We moving to Azure Data Lake Gen 2. Here is the question, can we still use the .NET Framework to pointing to Azure Data Lake Gen 2 i.e. will Gen 2 will be supported with .NET Framework?

Comment: Hello, if the answer is helpful, please accept it as answer as per [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you're using code (based on the .NET Framework) to operate with ADLS Gen2, yes, it's definitely ok.

Please let me know if you have other concerns.